# Is it safe to call native function that locks pixels of Bitmap from non UI thread?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm implementing list that contains preview of different image filters (grayscale, sepia, etc.)

I want to move image processing out of UI thread, but I'm not sure is it safe. For example, when I'm calling `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels` for `Bitmap` of `ImageView` what will happen if UI thread will try to redraw `ImageVIew`?

**EXAMPLE**

```
public void someMethod(){
    ImageView mImageView = /*initialization*/
    final Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            applyFilter(bmp);
        }
    }).start();
}

public native void applyFilter(Bitmap bmp);
```

Comment: could you please post a sample?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this case yet; however, you're trying to modify the current being-used `Bitmap` on `ImageView`. I think when `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels` is called, some abnormal will happen, like crash on `ImageView` while trying to `invalidate` or something similar to `Access Violation`.
You can make a copy of the image, process it then apply the new `Bitmap` to `ImageView`; it's totally safe.

Comment: There is no problems if Im modifying bitmap in UI thread, since ImageView wont be invalidated until processing is done.  Make a copy - it's an idea, but as I said Im creating preview images. So a lot of copies will be created. Any way ta avoid this? P.S. personal thanks for your "sepia" article :)

Comment: If not making copies, so how many images will be processed/displayed in total? also if making copies? could you please provide also the size of images and their quality? It's gonna be a real deal if you're trying to process tons of images at a time.

Comment: 6 png images not larger than 300x300. If I'll make copies there will be 12 images :)

Answer (score 1):

In that case, there's a chance that the Bitmap is directly referencing something in that ImageView. Otherwise, the Bitmap becomes just another set of 1s and 0s. You might be able to make a copy of the Bitmap and update the ImageView with the new image once you are done. Be careful about images on devices before Honeycomb (3.0) because they handle bitmaps weird, and you have to manage them almost like you would in a C++ program.

It shouldn't, but there's sometimes hidden things in Android, so watch out.

Update: there might be a way to modify the image without copying, but I'm basing this more off general graphics and not Android-specific